# How to select related row when current row is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+---------+---------+
| id |  name   | related |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | Jack    | 1       |
| 2  |         | 1       |
| 3  |         | 1       |
| 4  |         | 2       |
| 5  | peter   | 2       |
| 6  | peter   | 2       |
| 7  |         | 2       |
| 8  | jhon    | 4       |
| 9  |         | 3       |
| 19 | ali     | 3       |
| 20 |         | 4       |
| 21 |         | 4       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

All I have is a id-number, Here is my query:

```
SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1
```

In my query sometimes `name` is empty. So I'm trying to select related name, how can I do that?

Here is some example: *(plus expected output)*

```
:id = 1
+---------+
| Jack    |
+---------+

:id = 2
+---------+
| Jack    |
+---------+

:id = 21
+---------+
| jhon    |
+---------+

:id = 6
+---------+
| peter   |
+---------+
```

Comment: @Chris What? do you know what I'm trying to get?

Comment: Just get the related id from your id value as a sub query and then find the row where it actually has a name.

Answer (score 1):

The query below will work with ids 1, 2 and 6.  I'm not sure how to get id 21 to equal jhon.  If I join the table four times I get to Jack.  I hope this helps.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN A.name IS NULL THEN B.name ELSE A.name END) 
FROM mytable A LEFT JOIN mytable B ON (A.related=B.id)
```