# How to use join but just get the rows of first table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have these two tables:

```
// one
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | aaa   |
| 2  | bbb   |
| 3  | ccc   |
+----+-------+

// two
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 2  | ddd   |
| 3  | eee   |
| 4  | fff   |
+----+-------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT one.value FROM one JOIN two ON one.id = two.id
```

And here is **current result:**

```
// 4 rows
+-----+
| bbb |
|     |
| ccc |
|     |
+-----+
```

And here is **expected output:**

```
// 2 rows
+-----+
| bbb |
| ccc |
+-----+
```

As you see I'm trying to *only* select the rows from `one` table. How can I do that?

Comment: Your query looks right to me.  I don't think it would return 4 results based on your sample data, it should return your expected results.

Comment: And the working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a70df8/1

Comment: @sgeddes Ah ok thank you .. I think I couldn't simulate my real problem ..

Comment: @sgeddes You know, why sometimes there is some redundant rows?

Comment: Can you create an updated fiddle with the problem you're having?  As is, it's difficult to guess what's going on.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `qanda` shows two rows with empty subject.

Comment: @Bulat All I want to know, why the result is *5 rows* ? The number of rows is depend of what thing in `join` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this in your sql fiddle:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) from events
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

You can notice that each `qanda` has several associated events, hence you are getting all events that have matching `post_id`.

If you are expecting two rows, add `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.id, ee.table_code, q.subject 
FROM 
  qanda q JOIN 
  events ee on ee.post_id = q.id and 
         ee.author_id = 31 and 
         ee.table_code = 15
```

Comment: You know what want? All I want to get is a subject, just one row, but sometimes `subject` is empty and then I need to use `related` column and find its subject. Is that possible?

Comment: have a look at `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ` structure.

Comment: Some thing like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259513/how-to-select-related-row-when-current-row-is-empty

Comment: @stack yes, that is a hood example

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
SELECT table1.value FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

This basically Equi join

you can refer more about Equi Join here [here](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-equi-join.php)